# Not able to install weave on coreos on vm

Tags: vagrant, weave

I am trying to install weave on CoreOS (647.2.0, stable) on a Vagrant VM. In the `user-data` file, I had added the units for its installation.

When I set-up the VM and log in to it, I find that Weave is not installed.

On running `systemctl status install-weave`, the output that I get is,

```
 install-weave.service - Install Weave
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/install-weave.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
 Docs: http://zettio.github.io/weave/
```